# I'm using CallBackFlow to return result whenever it is available but it shows error Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to return result from function using CallBackFlow but getting error,

```
private fun callSocket(
        eventEmmit: String,
        eventOn: String,
        request: JSONObject
    ) = callbackFlow {
            try {
                if (socket.connected()) {
                    var response: JSONObject
                    Log.e("EMIT $eventEmmit", JSONObject(Gson().toJson(request)).toString())

                    socket.on(
                        eventOn
                    ) { args ->
                        response = args[0] as JSONObject
                        Log.e("ON $eventOn", response.toString())
                        trySend(SocketCallback.OnSuccess(response))
                    }.emit(
                        eventEmmit,
                        request
                    )
                } else {
                    Log.e("SOCKET_ERROR", "Socket connection failed")
                    trySend(SocketCallback.OnError("Socket connection failed"))
                }
            } catch (e: SocketException) {
                Log.e("SOCKET_ERROR", "Socket connection failed")
                trySend(SocketCallback.OnError("Socket connection failed"))
            }
            awaitClose { cancel() }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help with how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a little too complicated in this case for the compiler to figure out the type implicitly, so you just have to be explicit:

```
callbackFlow<YourReturnType> {
```

Comment: That also doesn't work, Same error.

Comment: So what's the new error message? I don't know what API you're using and can't test your code. It doesn't make sense for it to have an error about inferring T when your code has explicit T.

Comment: "Unresolved reference: trySend" on trySend().

Comment: I'm trying to call socket and it does work perfectly in other project but it is causing issue in this project only. We are using same structure in other 3 projects.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, sorry. I can't explain why it wouldn't be able to find `trySend` which isn't even an extension function of `ProducerScope`.

Comment: It shows ProducerScope<Nothing> that's why it is showing an error and in other project it is able to find the trySend() function.